# Can I use a Crosswalk extension with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I have a Crosswalk extension (and not a Cordova plugin), and I want to use it in a Cordova application (which uses the Crosswalk webview via the cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview).

Is this possible?
How do I configure it?

Comment: Which kind of plugin do you plan to use in your app?

Comment: We have a inhouse developed plugin (some time ago) that signals the headset button and controls the power (wakelock). It also allows to activate the device when the screen and keyboard are off based on a network event

Comment: But are you talkin about a custom Cordova plugin? I've never heard of Crosswalk plugins...

Comment: It's officially called Crosswalk extensions https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/android_extensions/write_an_extension.html

Comment: So I suggest to use this name in order to avoid mis-understanding